# Animating div height without distorting the image

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to scale up the container image without distorting the image.

While updating height seems to work, the container is scaling below and not above as I want it.

Here is a small prototype I am trying to make.

https://codepen.io/nicu-barbaro/pen/ExxdKZK

```
 .slider-item {
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  margin: 0 10px;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
    transform: scaleY(1.5);

  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: clip-path 1s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
  }
}
```

Here is a similar effect of scaling I want to achieve https://dribbble.com/shots/4815842-User-Reviews-Micro-Interactions?utm_source=Clipboard_Shot&utm_campaign=UI8&utm_content=User%20Reviews%20Micro%20Interactions&utm_medium=Social_Share .

Comment: I can see the distortion happening in your prototype, but could you describe in more detail what you want the images to do instead? What do you mean by "the container is scaling below and not above as I want it"?

Comment: @Tess Iv updated the question with an example of a similar effect. 

I mean that if you change the height of a div, it will scale downwards, because the origin is above. However if I use the scale property I could alter the image origin by setting `transform-origin: bottom bottom` for example. And in this case If I scale the image on Y direction it will scale upwords. However this property does not affect height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `object-fit: cover` for images and it looks like it does not affect, but it does. You can not see it, because you are scaling parent `div` element - the key word is `scaling`. So, to have a result you want and not to be depended on parent `div` or `img` height you should apply the proportional for image. If you've set `transform: scaleY(1.5);` for parent div, set `transform: scaleX(1.5);` for child image:

Here an example based on your code:

https://codepen.io/Nevados/pen/yLLRvMd

P.S. If you want to align image by center, you can apply `translate` propetry for `img` according to scaling value.

Comment: Looks like I can align it by setting origin of the img to bottom bottom.